# How to unit test a function in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to create a unit test for the child controller
In my child controller, I called a function in the parent

child controller

```
$scope.clickMe = function(){
    $scope.parentMethod();
})
```

Parent controller

```
$scope.parentMethod = function(item){
    //do something with parent
})
```

Unit test

```
var childCtrl;

 beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
        scope        = _$rootScope_.$new();
        childCtrl = _$controller_('childCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    describe('test parent', function() {
        it('should call parent', function() {
            $scope.clickMe();
            $httpBackend.flush();
        });
    });
});
```

I am getting

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.parentMethod()')
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: unit testing is about testing a unit. you should write your unit test the way that they do not depend on each other. I recommend using mocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mock the method in scope for sake of testing child controller

```
    scope        = _$rootScope_.$new();
    scope.parentMethod = function noop(){};
    childCtrl = _$controller_('childCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });
```

For testing noop should be replaced with a spy. Syntax will depend upon the engine you're using Jasmine or Sinon. This way in test it will be possible to verify that `parentMethod` was called.